# Is it possible to define a jsonSchema for the jsonSchema specification?

Tags: json, validation, metadata, jsonschema

Im attemting to build a form using the [react-jsonschema-form](https://github.com/rjsf-team/react-jsonschema-form) library, and reading the [specification](http://json-schema.org/) I want to know if its possible to build a schema that defines the JSONSchema specification its self.

Is it easy to prove whether or not this is possible?

Comment: Yes, and it is official as per your link. I would probably suggest you delete this question, but please feel free to ask more and join the our JSON Schema slack server. Discussion link on the official site. =]

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/rjsf-team/react-jsonschema-form/issues/1465

^ this is an issue raised on the GH repo

regarding Meta schemas for the JSON Schema: http://json-schema.org/specification.html#meta-schemas